# magento 2.0 theme not working in 2.1

Tags: magento2, css, magento-2.1, deploy

I created a theme in **magento 2.0** that was working. Now, I updated the magento version to **2.1** and deployed the theme. The files get generated in **pub/static** folder but CSS files are not loading in head section. I am loading the CSS files as below:

**default_head_blocks.xml**

```
 <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>

        <css src="css/test.css" />
        <css src="css/owl.carousel.css" />
        <link src="js/owl.carousel.js"/> 

    </head>
</page>
```

Comment: Try this app/design/frontend/theme/web/css/test.css. I also face same problem after this it's working for me

Comment: @Kothari do you understand the question?

Comment: Oh Sorry @Qaisar Satti No Idea

Comment: plz show your xml file

Comment: @Rakesh updated the question.

Comment: Have you keep your test.css file inside app/design/frontend/Vendor/themename/web/css/test.css

Comment: @Rakesh it's working in magento 2.0 but problem with 2.1 version.

Comment: Have you keep above file at proper location? may be you have forgot to put file at proper location

Comment: @Rakesh i can see file have been deployed  in pub/static folder so no problem there..

Comment: And the XML is in app/design/frontend/Vendor/themename/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml?

Comment: @RobertEgginton yes...

Comment: @QaisarSatti: Hi did u able to solve ur issue with waqar's below answer?? Bcz i tried that one but didn't worked. I'm also facing similar issue. 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/190204/magento-production-custom-theme-custom-css-file-is-not-loading

Comment: @Anjana this is different question you are asking.

Comment: @QaisarSatti: Ok can you then help me with my question?

Comment: @Anjana no idea dear what you missed their.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was facing the same problem and did the following steps to fix it

1. First make a backup of your theme from `app/design/frontend/theme`
2. Set the blank theme from `admin->content->configurations` for your
   store
3. delete the theme from `admin->themes->your-theme`
4. also delete it form folder  `app/design/frontend/theme`
5. then run **upgrade** and deploy commands.
6. then place your theme again in folder `app/design/frontend/theme`
7. run **upgrade** command.
8. select your theme from `admin->content->configurations->your-theme`
   for your store.
9. and run **deploy** command.

Hope it will work for you also.

Comment: Is possible magento 2.0.0 theme fot magento 2.1.7?

Comment: @Qaisar Satti AFter applied the theme the screen look like https://snag.gy/25jdHU.jpg

Comment: @zus you need to deploy theme content just follow https://blog.qaisarsatti.com/magento_2/magento-2-deploy-static-content-theme/

Comment: @QaisarSatti Still not working, may i know the proper way to import magento 2 themes.

Comment: @zus the problem you showing is image is related to static content. for import the data of custom theme. there will be configuration for that.

Comment: @QaisarSatti Can i get any reference for import magento 2 theme?

Comment: @QaisarSatti Maybe my theme import steps wrong, so that can you suggest me any reference for import magento 2 theme.

Comment: @zus which theme you are importing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75084/discussion-between-zus-and-qaisar-satti).

Comment: Could you pls join with chat session.